# Javascript - how can I get the value of the response json object from async fetch that calls python function

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

```
    const [response, asxAnnouncement] = await Promise.all([
    fetch("/callback/getStock?data=" + Stock + "&period=" + Interval),
    fetch("/callback/getAsxAnnouncement?data=" + Stock)

    if (asxAnnouncement.ok) {
       var asx_announcement_response = await asxAnnouncement.json();
       if (asxAnnouncement.ok) {
         var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(asx_announcement_response);
         console.log(jsonObj);
```

backend Python function returns the response message

```
       companyAnnouncement = pyasx.data.companies.get_company_announcements(stock)
       return jsonify({'companyAnnouncement': companyAnnouncement})
```

the console.log showed the response messages like the below:

```
{"companyAnnouncement":
  [
    {
        "document_date":"Mon, 30 Oct 2023 21:01:27 GMT",
        "num_pages":12,
        "release_date":"Mon, 30 Oct 2023 21:20:28 GMT",
        "size":"782.9KB",
        "title":"Quarterly activities report and Appendix 4C - September 2023",
        "url":"https://announcements.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20231031/pdf/05wr5p029g0ydw.pdf"
    },
    {
        "document_date":"Wed, 25 Oct 2023 22:41:58 GMT",
        "num_pages":35,"
        release_date":"Wed, 25 Oct 2023 22:46:42 GMT",
        "size":"10.4MB",
        "title":"Annual General Meeting presentation",
        "url":"https://announcements.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20231026/pdf/05wjbq1nn2c09q.pdf"}
    ,
    {   "document_date":"Wed, 20 Sep 2023 04:13:42 GMT",
        "num_pages":1,
        "release_date":"Wed, 20 Sep 2023 04:24:46 GMT",
        "size":"167.6KB",
        "title":"Cann to supply additional flower products to key customer",
        "url":"https://announcements.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20230920/pdf/05v2xpwm4vxst1.pdf"
    },
    {   "document_date":"Sun, 29 Jan 2023 22:24:35 GMT",
        "num_pages":9,
        "release_date":"Sun, 29 Jan 2023 22:26:23 GMT",
        "size":"415.7KB",
        "title":"Quarterly Activities and Appendix 4C Cashflow Report",
        "url":"https://announcements.asx.com.au/asxpdf/20230130/pdf/45l1qkcn9b25bn.pdf"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am googling the solution and trying so many times with no success. Can anyone give me some hint and advice.

```
I want to retrieve the value, like title and url, from the return JSON object shown above. but it is not working.

$.each(asx_announcement_response, function(index, val) {
    console.log(val);
     tab += `<li style="padding-bottom:5px;"><a class="pluslink" href="${val.url}}">${val.title}</a></li>`;
}
document.getElementById("asxAnnouncement").innerHTML = tab;


The problem is I am not able to get the val value. it only shows object instead of the value of URL and title.
```

Comment: "the console.log showed the response messages like the below:" not sure I understand what is the issue then :)

Comment: i can't receive value from the response JSON object. i have tried the following but not working

$.each(asx_announcement_response, function(index, val) {
   console.log(val);

Comment: `asx_announcement_response.companyAnnouncement` will be an array, not `asx_announcement_response`, that is an object

Comment: so what you want instead is: `$.each(asx_announcement_response.companyAnnouncement, function(index, val)`

Comment: It is working now. thank. Elvis.

Comment: you are very welcome